# Manually set the locale in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I was wondering how one could manually change the locale for a SailsJS app. What I am envisioning is having a dropdown on the top nav bar from which the user can change the language that they want the site to be displayed in.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to adapt your config/i18n.js in the sails project to configure your locales, default locale, and perhaps a custom cookie name.

Then you can use [setLocale('myLocaleName')](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node#setlocale) to set the locale based on what gets selected in your dropdown. The link provides a detailed description on how to do this.

Good luck

Daniel

Comment: Great answer-- to add to this, here's a link to the relevant docs: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/internationalization/locales#?detecting-and-or-overriding-the-desired-locale-for-a-request